# What does this participial construction mean?

Tags: participles

> "I think I've got a good idea of what's been going on," said Professor
>   McGonagall. "It doesn't take a genius to work it out. You fed Draco
>   Malfoy some cock-and-bull story about a dragon, **trying to get him
>   out of bed and into trouble**. I've already caught him. I suppose you
>   think it's funny that Longbottom here heard the story and believed it,
>   too?" (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

The bold phrase seems to say about the intention of the action in main clause. Can a participial construction denote the meaning?

Comment: You fed Draco Malfoy some cock-and-bull story about a dragon, trying to get him out of bed and into trouble. = You fed Draco Malfoy some cock-and-bull story about a dragon, while you are trying to get him out of bed and into trouble.

Comment: @JayHook: Perhaps better, *You fed Draco Malfoy some cock-and-bull story about a dragon, **in an attempt to** get him out of bed and into trouble.* These weren't two activities that just happened to take place at the same time, which is often the implication using ***while*** like that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sounds like an answer to me; I was about to write something similar. If you post it I'll upvote :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, let's clarify what we mean by the term...

> a [participial phrase](http://www.sinclair.edu/centers/tlc/pub/handouts_worksheets/grammar_punctuation_writing/phrase_participial.pdf) *is always used as an adjective phrase to **modify** a noun or pronoun. It includes the participle together with its modifiers, objects, or predicate words.*

And here are the first few few examples from that link...

> 1. ***Having been on the road for four days**, the Todds were exhausted.*
> 2. *That hymn, **sung by many generations of churchgoers,** is my favorite.*
> 3. ***Climbing slowly,** we approached the top of the hill.*
> 4. ***Surprised by my question,** Mrs. Osmond blushed.*

Note that in *all* cases, the participial phrase provides additional information *that could grammatically (and usually logically) be omitted*. But other than that there's no particular restriction on the kind of information it provides, or how it relates to the noun it modifies *(the Todds, that hymn, us, Mrs. Osmond)*.

Although examples #1 and #4 don't actually embody "intention", they do explain *why* the main clause arises. And #3 could have been ***Hoping for a better view,*** we climbed to the top of the hill, in which case rather than saying *how* we climbed, the participial phrase would convey intention (i.e. - *why* we did it).

OP's example explains ***why*** [the boys?] fed Draco Malfoy a cock-and-bull story. Perfectly ordinary.